# javascript/children- check value of alt for an image

Tags: javascript, alt

I have an array of image elements. Each image has a specific alt value:

```
<img src="dice1" alt="1" onclick="change(this);">
<img src="dice2" alt="2" onclick="change(this);">
etc,etc,etc.
```

I want to loop through the array, and change an image based on its alt value. In this case, when an image is clicked, it will be replaced by the image whose alt value corresponds to a randomly generated number from 1 to 6, as the code attempts to demonstrate:

```
function change(diceToChange) {
    var imgArray = getElementsByTagName("img");
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        **if alt value of imgArray[i] equals randNum** {  <-- something like this
            diceToChange.style.display = "none";
            imgArray[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Is this even possible using javascript? What statement would make this work?

Comment: `if (imgArray[i].getAttribute('alt') == randNum)`

Comment: It is very much possible.  What I understand from program is you want to hide those dice that match your random number between 1 and 6 both included.

Comment: actually I want to show the one that matches the random number. I forgot to mention that the display for all dice, save dice1, are set to "none".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute)

```
function change(diceToChange) {
    var imgArray = getElementsByTagName("img");
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        if (imgArray[i].getAttribute('alt') == randNum) { 
            diceToChange.style.display = "none";
            imgArray[i].style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `HTMLImageElement` has the `alt` property so no need to use `getAttribute` here

```
imgArray[i].alt == randNum
```

Comment: had a hard time choosing a best answer for this one.